# Mock exported const arrow functions with Jest

Tags: javascript, jestjs

Given the following example with a basic test, I'd expect `bar` to be returned when `sendMessage.message` is mocked with Jest. Instead, when called, it returns the original value of "Hello World".

#### serviceBus.js

```js
export const message = () => {
  return "Hello world";
};

export const foo = () => {
  return message();
};
```

#### mockDemo.test.js

```js
import * as sendMessage from "../src/services/serviceBus";

describe("sendMessage", () => {
  sendMessage.message = jest.fn(() => {
    return "bar";
  });

  it(`message should return bar`, async () => {
    expect(sendMessage.message()).toBe("bar");
    expect(sendMessage.foo()).toBe("bar");
  });
});
```

And the results as follows:

```js
$ ./node_modules/.bin/jest ./__tests__/mockDemo.test.js
 FAIL  __tests__/mockDemo.test.js
  MessageReceiver Router
    ✕ message should return bar (9ms)

  ● MessageReceiver Router › message should return bar

    expect(received).toBe(expected) // Object.is equality

    Expected: "bar"
    Received: "Hello world"

       9 |   it(`message should return bar`, async () => {
      10 |     expect(sendMessage.message()).toBe("bar");
    > 11 |     expect(sendMessage.foo()).toBe("bar");
         |                               ^
      12 |   });
      13 | });
      14 |

      at Object.<anonymous> (__tests__/mockDemo.test.js:11:31)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       1 failed, 1 total
```

It looks as if `sendMessage.foo` is calling the bound function once imported of `message`, which by default returns `Hello World`.

How would one mock `message` in this context?

#### Update

Using `jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => "bar");` results in the same behaviour:

```js
describe("MessageReceiver Router", () => {
  //   sendMessage.message.mockImplementation = jest.fn(() => {
  //     return "bar";
  //   });

  sendMessage.message = jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => "bar");

  it(`message should return bar`, async () => {
    expect(sendMessage.message()).toBe("bar");
    expect(sendMessage.foo()).toBe("bar");
  });
});
```

Results:

```
$ ./node_modules/.bin/jest ./__tests__/mockDemo.test.js
 FAIL  __tests__/mockDemo.test.js
  MessageReceiver Router
    ✕ message should return bar (10ms)

  ● MessageReceiver Router › message should return bar

    expect(received).toBe(expected) // Object.is equality

    Expected: "bar"
    Received: "Hello world"

      11 |   it(`message should return bar`, async () => {
      12 |     expect(sendMessage.message()).toBe("bar");
    > 13 |     expect(sendMessage.foo()).toBe("bar");
         |                               ^
      14 |   });
      15 | });
      16 |

      at Object.<anonymous> (__tests__/mockDemo.test.js:13:31)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       1 failed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        2.175s
```

Comment: `sendMessage.message.mockImplementation`?

Comment: Doesn't work unfortunately :/

Comment: Ah. It has been closed over. So you may not be able to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So internal functions called *cannot* be mocked or spyed on. To fix this, you need to create an **object** of services, and export that instead.

#### serviceBus.js

```js
const message = () => {
  return "Hello world";
};

const foo = () => {
  return services.message();
};

const services = {
  message,
  foo
};

export default services;
```

#### mockDemo.test.js

```js
import sendMessage from "../src/services/serviceBus";

describe("MessageReceiver Router", () => {
  sendMessage.message = jest.fn(() => {
    return "bar";
  });

  it(`message should return bar`, async () => {
    expect(sendMessage.message()).toBe("bar");
    expect(sendMessage.foo()).toBe("bar");
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `spyOn` method to mock the `sendMessage.message` method.

```
import * as sendMessage from "../src/services/serviceBus";

describe("sendMessage", () => {
   jest.spyOn(sendMessage, 'message').mockReturnValue("bar")

  it(`message should return bar`, async () => {
    expect(sendMessage.message()).toBe("bar");
    expect(sendMessage.foo()).toBe("bar");
  });
});
```